# playing audio and recording video on iphone simultaneously

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to play audio and record video from camera at the same time in my app.

How I can to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do that. Have you tried anything so far? Some documents of interest:
- [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)
- [AVCaptureSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
As well a plethora of other related classes. It's impossible to be more precise without knowing specifics of your requirements though.